# 'Button' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im a noob in React.js , and just messing around with components and event listeners , i am trying to Add eventlistener to button but it doesnt work for some reason... I tried to import elemental but that just gives a bunch of other errors  , can somone please tell me how i can get this to work ? thanks

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';



class Passiing extends React.Component {
  scream() {
    alert('you passed!');
  }

  render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.scream}>Did you pass?</Button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('app'));



export default Passiing;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to import Button using react-bootstrap.

import { Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

In order for the style to appear, please install bootstrap and 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' and add it in index.js

To use button,

Submit[image]

Comment: ...if you happen to be using react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to use react-bootstrap ? if so, add this import:
`import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'`, if you haven't installed it yet, run these command:

```
$ npm install --save react react-dom
$ npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

if you have no intent to use use it, you have to create a component called Button yourself and import it.

Comment: thanks it works now , but for some reason the styling is not appearing ?

Comment: return <Button bsSize="small" onClick={this.scream}>AAAAAH!</Button>;

Comment: what do you mean by style is not appearing?

Comment: the button is still in default form ,  https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/ i m trying to make it like the buttons in the demo , but bsStyle =''primary' is not changing it

Comment: makes no sense, check if there is no spelling error.

Comment: how do i add css or bootstrap  to the buttons?

Comment: as you are using a premade component, you can't add your own style, but if you create your own component, they have a prop called style, there you can pass CSS to it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the HTML5 `<button>` tag for your button. If you use a capital letter for a tag in React it assumes that is a component rather than a "regular" tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly as stated in the error. You're using a `Button` component that is not defined anywhere. You need to either define a `Button` class or import `Button` from somewhere (e.g. a UI library).

Comment: Would be interested in hearing the rationale for the downvote. This is exactly what's happening.

Comment: maybe he wanted how to do it? no reason for a downvote, will upvote you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like that.

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';



class Passiing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.scream = this.scream.bind(this);
  }
  scream() {
    alert('you passed!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type='button' value="button" onClick={this.scream} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Passiing/>, document.getElementById('app'));



export default Passiing;
```